# Run web application only inside a particular .EXE

Tags: sql, asp.net, exe, ws-security

I have a web application, which run in all browsers using `ASP.NET, SQLSERVER`.
Since its relating to transferring funds and transmitting vouchers any one can use this from anywhere in the world.
Only user name and password are the security parameters used here.

We are facing an issue in the security side, any sales agent / customer who got this credentials can make transactions on that particular dealers account.

Is it possible to launch the web-app only inside an .EXE file, which can act as a parent to run my web-app.

So any anyone suggest an idea to  do this mechanism /or a better solution to overcome this obstacle?

Comment: 3rd paragraph uses "web-app" twice but appears to be for different things. I cannot even workout if you want to package up the server side (usually called web app) or the client (browser).

Comment: @Richard, Its a server side web application, enable the vendors to make mobile payments through the browsers.

I ll give the link of my application , as well the credentials to access it, and that is the working mechanism.

But any one with the link and credentials may misuse it.

Comment: OWIN allows exe's to host ASP.NET-MVC applications: there are plenty of introductions out there. But remember if you do not control the hosting environment, a malicious hoster has a lot of potential access.

Comment: Why would an EXE stop a person using credentials incorrectly??? If you ran it in an EXE it is now a thick client and no longer "can use this from anywhere in the world"

Comment: I mean , that EXE can be only installed and circulated to registered clients.
Unlike web, availability of the concern EXE will make us some what controlled.

Answer (score 0):

1) Change your application to use [two-factor authentication.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication)

2) User best-practices for application security -- no magic fix ever guarantees real security.